# How to open Gmail links in Gmail app or browser?

Tags: gmail, hyperlinks

I often use links to some of my Gmail messages; these links have the form:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/XXXXXXXXXX
```

and I use them for future reference in, for instance, Evernote notes.

When I open such a link in Chrome on my desktop, the corresponding mail message is opened as expected. However, if I open those links in Chrome for Android, I only get the main window of Gmail, not that specific message.

Does anybody know of a way to open permanent links to Gmail messages in an Android app?

Answer (score 2):

As of 5 Oct '18, and as far as I am aware, there is no way to do so. The desktop web interface, mobile interface, and mobile application use different unique IDs and links for the messages.

For instance, using the desktop interface, you get the `main/u/#/` links. On mobile web, you get `mail/mu/mp/###/` links. There is no way to correspond the two.

Furthermore, the UUIDs are different for the interfaces. On mobile, you get a ~16 alpha-numeric ID. On desktop, it is ~35 alpha-numeric.

Maybe there is a method that the mobile web interface uses to shorten the length of the desktop IDs, but I can only speculate as to what it is.

But none of that would matter, because you would have to feed the link into a program or script to convert the link to/from whatever.

This does not even cover the use of multiple accounts, which have their own number in the links for the desktop and mobile web interfaces.

**That being said**

There is a sort of workaround that you might try. It requires a bit more work than copy-paste of a link, and it does not get you the desired outcome, but it is close.

Taken from a [Web Applications Answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/78875), you can modify your link to be a search result instead.

Follow his workaround steps. Getting the original message ID.

Your mobile link should look something like this:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/mu/mp/###/#tl/search/rfcmsgid%3A<MESSAGE.ID>
```

And the desktop link:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/#/#search/rfc822msgid%3A<MESSAGE.ID>
```

It adds to the number of items you will have listed in your notes, but it should get the job 85% done.