# Obtain a link to a specific email in Gmail Android app

Tags: gmail, hyperlinks

How can I obtain a link (a URL) to a specific email (or the entire thread, if necessary) in the Gmail Android app? I want to be able to click that link and open the specific email.

Comment: Have you tried to copy a link from the GMail web UI and use it on Android? Apps can register for web URLs of a certain pattern, may be GMail app can just handle those links from the web interface?

Comment: Possibly partially related/duplicate: [How to open Gmail links in Gmail app or browser?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/92035/44325) (it's the reverse situation, but also explains some potential technical difficulties, if the answer is still not outdated).

Comment: I think it can't be a direct link to the email.

Comment: @Robert I am looking to get the link from the Android app, specifically. I can definitely do it on the web, but this question is about the Android app. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible without coding up a custom solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: My explanation is that there are no existing solutions for this. There is not a lot of 'evidence' to point to, as it is the *lack* of a solution that is causing me to give the answer I am giving.